# mule : Merge List of maps into single Map

Tags: mule

I have scattergather in my flow, the output of which is a List of Maps, How can I convert that into a single Map in mule?

I have tried combine-collections-transfomer, flatten payload. Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you following dataweave code, but it will override duplicate keys

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{(payload)}
```

[image: Dataweave Snapshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to flatten list of lists which contains map using dataweave?

Comment: Use `flatten` keyword to flatten list first and then merge map like `{(flatten payload)}`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a custom Java Transformer so you can easily handle special situations such as duplicate keys with different values. A DataWeave function may also be able to do the trick, but you'll need Mule EE.

With a Transformer it's a simple question of Java code:

```
public class MyMapFlattener extends AbstractMessageTransformer{

    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

        //assuming your payload is the list of map
        List<Map<?, ?>> listOfMap = message.getPayload();

        Map<Object, Object> finalMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        for(Map<?, ?> map : listOfMap){
            //you can use putAll if you don't care about duplicates
            //finalMap.putAll(map);

            // or a more complex algorithm to handle duplicates
            for(Entry<?, ?> e : map.entrySet()){
                if(finalMap.containsKey(e.getKey())){
                    //do something to handle situation when key is duplicate...
                    //you may want to check if both values are equals and skip this
                    //maybe throw an exception if values are different
                    //or keep a value
                    throw new Exception("Duplicate: " + e);
                } else {
                    //key does not exists, put it
                    finalMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        return finalMap;

    }
}
```

And then use this transformer in your flow. [See the docs for details.](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/java-transformer-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways of doing this one of which is flatten operator which merges 2 arrays into a single array. The other is to do it through the Dataweave Transform map operator and merging them as per your requirements.